# order the object array based on price javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I would like to know how to order top 3 object array based on price (from max to min) in javascript.

```
var obj =[{
  id: "1",
  price: 20
},{
  id: "2",
  price: 50,
},{
 id: "3",
 price: 100
},{
  id: "4",
  price: 30
},{
  id: "5",
  price: 80
}]
```

Expected Output

```
result = [{
  id: "3",
  price: 100
 },{
  id: "5",
  price: 80
},{
  id: "2",
  price: 50,
}]
```

Comment: Why not use sort? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be easily achieved with [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

This function **returns a sorted array**, and does not change the original.

```
var obj =[{
  id: "1",
  price: 20
},{
  id: "2",
  price: 50,
},{
 id: "3",
 price: 100
},{
  id: "4",
  price: 30
},{
  id: "5",
  price: 80
}]

function compare(a, b) {
  if(a.price > b.price)
     return 1;
  if(a.price < b.price)
     return -1;
  // Equals
  return 0;
}

var sorted = obj.sort(compare);
```

Check the results and you might need to switch between the `return 1` and `return -1`. I honestly never remember which is ascending or descending :facepalm:

Now, if you wanna get the top 3 simply slice the array

```
var top3 = sorted.slice(0, 3);
```

Comment: thanks but want to get max top 3 in object array

Comment: add `.slice(3)` to the sorted array. Updated the answer to include that as well.

Comment: `.slice(0, 3)` - fixed answer as well. Did it help @miyavv?

Comment: yes, thanks for solution